# Copy link to message by RFC 822 Message-ID, e.g., via Chrome Extension or Gmail Labs

Tags: google-chrome, gmail, google-chrome-extensions

When I'm looking at a Gmail conversation or message, I'd like to copy a shareable link to a given message in the conversation. I want to share the link with someone else who already has a copy of the message.

I can construct a link to the message by clicking Show Original, copying the value of the Message-ID header, and pasting it into a link template like `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#search/rfc822msgid%3A{Message-ID}`.

I'd prefer a Chrome Extension or Gmail Labs feature that adds a button to "Get Link" to the Gmail conversation or message view.

Does an extension or labs feature exist? If so, where can I find it?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a Chrome bookmarklet.

Make a bookmark at a panel with the following code in the URL field:

```
javascript:window.location="https://gmail.com/#search/rfc822msgid:"+encodeURIComponent(window.document.body.innerHTML.match(/Message-ID: &lt;(.*)&gt;/)[1])+"/"+encodeURIComponent(window.location.search.toString().slice(1).split('&').filter(function(x){return x.slice(0,3) == "th="})[0].slice(3));
```

Then in Gmail you should open an original code of a message (from the menu in the right top corner of a message block) and click the bookmarklet. It will open a new tab with a generated URL with message id that you can copy with hotkeys.

This method isn't very handy and needs a couple of actions just to copy the link, but it's the only solution I've found by now.

I'm already about writting my Chrome extension to make it in one click, but it needs free time for developing.